# tensorflow build fails with “BUILD file not found on package”

Tags: android, tensorflow, bazel

I trying build tensorflow_demo for android with Bazel, but I get this error:

```
ERROR: no such package 'tensorflow/tensorflow/examples/android': BUILD file not found on package path.
```

I have build file in directory (MacOS):

```
 /Users/pavelgosteev/tensorflow/tensorflow/examples/android
```

build command:

```
(tensorflow) MBP-Pavel:tensorflow pavelgosteev$ bazel build //tensorflow/tensorflow/examples/android:tensorflow_demo
```

What's wrong? Why can't Bazel see build file?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need one fewer "tensorflow" in the build target name. Try:

```
bazel build //tensorflow/examples/android:tensorflow_demo
```

Further instructions can be found in the [Tensorflow Android tutorial](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/tree/master/tensorflow/examples/android/).